# Typescript: необязательная имплементация абстрактного метода

Tags: typescript

Допустим, в родительском классе нам необходимо сослаться на тот метод, который **возможно** будет имплементирован в унаследованном классе.

В приведённом примере ниже, метод `setOnInputListener` определяет обязательные действия, которые должны быть выполнены при вводе символа в поля ввода. Метод `onInput`, если он определён в унаследованном классе, позволяет добавить дополнительный функционал.

```
export default class CompoundInputField {

  // ...

  private setOnInputListener(): void {
    this.$AuthenticInputField.on('input', () => {
      this.updateInputFieldState();
      if (this.onInput){
        this.onInput(true);
      }
    });
  }

  protected onInput?(flag: any): void;
}
```

Это решение работает, но оно не совсем понятное. Какие есть лучшие альтернативы?

Способ `setOnInputListener(){ super.setOnInputListener() };` не подходит потому, что разработчик может просто-напросто забыть добавить `super.setOnInputListener()`.

Answer (score -2):

> Какие есть лучшие альтернативы?

просто ещё один способ.

```
abstract class CompoundInputField {
    protected $AuthenticInputField: any
    protected updateInputFieldState: any
    // ...
    input = () => {
        // this.updateInputFieldState();
        this.onInput.forEach(f => f(true))
    }
    private setOnInputListener(): void {
        this.$AuthenticInputField.on('input', this.input.bind(this));
    }
    // protected onInput?(flag: any): void;
    protected abstract onInput: ((...args: any[]) => void)[] = []
}
class EmailCompoundInputField extends CompoundInputField {
    protected onInput = [() => console.log('test')]
}
let q = new EmailCompoundInputField
q.input()//test
```