# TypeScript: Сделать protected метод родительского класса приватным в наследнике

Tags: typescript

Попробовал сделать такой пример на CodePen. Всё работает, то есть мы можем переопределять protected-методы родительского класса, при этом в очередном наследнике объявить его приватным.

```
class ParentClass {
    constructor(){}

  protected testMethod(){
    console.log('ParentClass.testMethod() called');
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    constructor(){ super(); }

  protected testMethod(){
    super.testMethod();
    console.log('ChildClass.testMethod() called');
  }
}

class GrandChild extends ParentClass {
    constructor(){ super(); }

  private testMethod(){
    super.testMethod();
    console.log('GrandChild.testMethod() called');
  }
}

let testInstance = new GrandChild();
testInstance.testMethod();
```

Тем не менее, когда я попробовал сделать тоже самое в реальном проекте, ничего не вышло:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фрагменты кода реального проекта:

```
export default class CompoundInputField {
  // ...
  protected setOnInputListener(): void {
    this.$AuthenticInputField.on('input', () => {
      this.updateInputFieldState();
      if (this.onInput){ this.onInput(true) }
    });
  }
}

export default class EmailCompoundInputField extends CompoundInputField {
  // ...
  private setOnInputListener(): void {
    super.setOnInputListener();
  }
}
```

Comment: [этот feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9677) был закрыт 2 года назад

Comment: @qwabra, не знаю, за что минусовали Ваш ответ, но я его немного улучшил материалом из комментария overthesanity. Всем остальным пользователям: если минусуете ответ, то пожалуйста, укажите в комментарии обоснование, чтобы ответ можно было улучшить.

Comment: @БоковГлеб, фух, думал опять что пропустил, как в [другом вашем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/868322). к стати, а что скажете по поводу идеи введения стека(массива). озвученной в ответе к тому вопросу?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

В современных версиях Typescript такая возможность не поддерживается. Запрос ввести такую возможность был отклонён со следующим обоснованием ([источкик](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9677)):

> This doesn't seem to fit what other OOP languages do. It also creates
>   the additional weirdness that there would be calls to a private method
>   coming from outside the class itself, which should normally be
>   disallowed.

### Подробнее

1. `protected` и `private` никакие не приватные и не защищённые, а также как и все торчат наружу - то есть это что-то вроде интерфейсов, видных только ide
2. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-protected

   > The protected modifier acts much like the private modifier with the exception that members declared protected can also be accessed within deriving classes.

   private - переменная доступна только внутри класса
   protected - только внутри класса и потомков

---

тут ide выдаст ошибку

```
class CompoundInputField {
    private setOnInputListener(): void {
        // --
    }
}
class EmailCompoundInputField extends CompoundInputField {
    private setOnInputListener(): void {
        super.setOnInputListener();
    }
}
```

тут - нет

```
class CompoundInputField {
    protected setOnInputListener(): void {
        // --
    }
}
class EmailCompoundInputField extends CompoundInputField {
    protected setOnInputListener(): void {
        super.setOnInputListener();
    }
}
```

повторюсь, это только в рамках IDE, в скомпилированном коде к переменной можно обратиться!
скомпилированный результат:

```
class CompoundInputField {
    setOnInputListener() {
    }
}
class EmailCompoundInputField extends CompoundInputField {
    setOnInputListener() {
        super.setOnInputListener();
    }
}
```